# using jquery with bootstrap toggle menu and submenu not shown

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing dynamic menu and submenu using json data. Firstly I click navbar menu then it shows list of menu but when I click the one of list of menu then submenu not showing. Therefore, again when I click navbar menu then the menu and it's submenu show.

But I want my code to work as,

1. click navbar menu -> list of menu show.
2. one of list menu click -> its submenu show.

But it is not working due to the above reasons.
Project demo link : 
http://128.199.194.110:8080/EBazaar/

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getSubCategory(){
  $.getJSON(
             "/EBazaar/prodList.json", 
             function(j) {
                  var html = '';
                  html+='<li class="divider"></li>';
                  for(var i=0; i<j.length; i++){
                   html+='<li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">'+j[i].categoryName+'</a>';
                   html+='<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
                   for(var k=0; k<j[i].subCategory.length; k++){
                   html+='<li><a href="<c:url value="/product/productList/'+j[i].categoryId+'/'+j[i].subCategory[k].subCategoryName+'" />">'+j[i].subCategory[k].subCategoryName+'</a></li>';  
                   }
                   html+='</ul>';
                   html+='</li>';
                  }
                  $('#allProduct').after(html);
             });
  
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li.dropdown [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); 
  event.stopPropagation(); 
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
 });
 
});

window.onload = function() {
  getSubCategory();
 };
</script>
```

```html
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header" >
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<c:url value="/" />"><img class="logo" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/logo-home.png" width="80px"></a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" >
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="<c:url value="/" />">Home</a></li>
                        
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     <li id="allProduct"><a href="<c:url value="/product/productList/all" />" >All Products</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        
                    </li>
```

Tutorial that I reference from below link, please see the dropdown bar.
The sample is not dynamic as it is using static data for menu and submenu and in my case I am using dynamic by fetching data through json:-
http://www.bootply.com/nZaxpxfiXz

Useful screenshot of my code problem.

[Step-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1ZeJ.jpg)

[image: Step-2]

[image: Step-3]
[image: Step-4]

Some useful screenshot of my code:-
Thank you very much.

Comment: can you give us a working demo of your current code please?

Comment: @Michael, I am not sure to give working demo because I used json fetch to build this menu. The sample code I copied from the link I given above. But you can get the demo of my project from here: http://128.199.194.110:8080/EBazaar/ . I think my doc.ready() work only once when nav bar click and show menu and after second time nav bar click then submenu show.